# SVG animation, CSS spin animation but stay on the same place

Tags: css, animation, svg

I am animating a propeller on my website.

http://bug.soulmates.company (See section 3)

But even though I set style to:

```
.propeller_spin {
   animation-name: spin;
   animation-duration: 4000ms;
   animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   transform-origin: center center;
 }

 @keyframes spin {
   from {
     transform:rotate(0deg);
     transform-origin: center center;
   }
   to {
     transform:rotate(360deg);
     transform-origin: center center;
   }
 }
```

The propeller doesn´t stay on it´s place while spinning.

Comment: Please add `.propeller_spin {transform-box: fill-box;}` [MDN link for transform-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOM elements measure transform-origin from their own top left corner, but SVG measures transform-origin relative to the parent SVG canvas.

You could use transform-box: fill-box on your .propeller_spin class.

[The transform-box CSS property defines the layout box to which the transform and transform-origin properties relate.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box)